# How to Plot Silhouette with Sørensen–Dice Similarity Coefficient

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

How to plot silhouette with Sørensen–Dice similarity coefficient? I already have the cluster result and distance value.

clust:

```
1
1
2
2
2
```

metric:

```
0.25733   0.002573   0.003551   0.000677   0.002871   0.005561   0.004473   0.115495   0.232204   0.198639
```

I tried to plot it with:

```
silhouette([],clust,metric)
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Silhouette value:

```
-0.9912
-0.9833
-0.9843
-0.9710
-0.9880
```

The distance value is treated as dissimilarity value. How to set matlab to use it as similarity value? It should be:

```
0.9912
0.9833
0.9843
0.9710
0.9880
```

Thanks.

Comment: Plot with `-metric`?

Comment: Hi, I want to plot it with Dice but there's no Dice option in the metric http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/silhouette.html. So I tried to plot it with my distance vector, but the silhouette values are negative.